# Gravatar no ruby-on-rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gravatar

Seguindo o tutorial do [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/244-gravatar?language=pt&view=asciicast) para adicionar uma imagem do site gravatar encontrei uma informação defasada com as atualizações do rails. O código para criar uma imagem default no caso de ausência de cadastro no site do gravatar não funciona como no código abaixo sugere. Já tentei trocar "images" por "assets", alguém possui alguma ideia que possa resolver o problema? segue o código:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(user)
    default_url = "#{root_url}assets/default.jpg"
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email).downcase
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48&d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"
  end
end
```

Segue o codigo da View que chama o a imagem:

```
<%= image_tag avatar_url(f) %>
```

Segue o link da imagem quebrada que a parece:

http://i2.wp.com/localhost/assets/default.jpg

Comment: Obrigado Sergio!

Answer (score 1):

O Gravatar é bem simples, coloque a linha abaixo no seu helper, 'app/helpers/application_helper.rb':

```
  def avatar_url(user)
    if user.url_image.present?
      user.url_image
    else
      gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
      "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48"
    end
  end
```

E em 'app/views/home/index.html', chame o helper passando o usuario atual como parâmetro:

```
Logado como <%= avatar_url(current_user) %> <%= current_user.email %>. Não é você?
```

O código do método é bem simples, primeiro ele verifica se existe alguma url de imagem no campo 'url_image' que você colocou anteriormente, senão ele vai utilizar o email do usuário como um id para buscar a imagem que está armazenada no Gravatar, o parâmetro 's=48' no final é para definir o tamanho que será dimensionada a imagem.

Fonte: http://vagnerzampieri.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/ruby-on-rails-do-zero-devise.html

Comment: Entretanto eu não estou usando um user para armazenar uma image. Eu gostaria de usar uma imagem default para todos que não possuem um email cadastrado. No railscast ele fala que pode ser feito isso pelo parâmetro 'd=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}' e que o default_url pegaria da pasta assets a minha imagem.

Comment: Esta dando algum erro?

Comment: A imagem não aparece. E pesquisando o caminho da imagem  não é o caminho que eu passei.

Comment: Tentou reiniciar o server? Faz o seguinte cola seu codigo da view ali na pergunta pra mim da uma olhada e o link que esta vindo.

Comment: Sim já tentei reiniciar o server. Editei atualizando a pergunta com as informações pedidas

Comment: Imagens de email ele consegue puxar e funciona normalmente. Só o caminho para a pasta onde encontra-se a imagem default que não funciona.

Comment: Cara, o path que vc esta passando la no default esta certo? em lugar de images tente #{root_url}assets/guest.png

Comment: sim eu troquei. "images" era usado na versão rails anterior a 3.2

Comment: Aparentemente esta ok seu código. Você tem ele no github? Talvez posso baixa-lo aqui e testar se quiser.

Comment: infelizmente não possuo ele no git. ele está em um repositório fechado.

Comment: tem skype? me passa ai.

Comment: ygorbr1. Me add la. Entretanto não poderei responder no momento.